# installing ROS on win

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I'm trying to install ros from here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Msvc%20SDK%20-%20Fuerte

point 3, when I write roscore on console2

---

process failed with error: 2

program variables:

python exe: python

executable: C:\opt\ros\fuerte\x86\bin\roscore.exe

python script: C:\opt\ros\fuerte\x86\bin\roscore

arguments: python C:\opt\ros\fuerte\x86\bin\roscore

---

does anyone know how to solve it?? thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35016/installing-ros-on-win/) by [marco.puni](https://answers.ros.org/users/2474/marco.puni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ffusion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2057/ffusion/) on 2012-05-30**:
I didn't even know it was already a windows version. Probably is still a bit buggy/inmature. Anyway, probably is better if you add information about which windows version you have an so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just figured out to solve this, the tutorial in the wiki was pretty vague about it.

Basically, what you need to do is to add C:\Python27\ and C:\Python27\Scripts to the PATH IN the Setup.bat. Not the path for python when you install it the first time.

Edit your PATH in setup.bat so that it looks like this -
set PATH=C:/opt/ros/fuerte/x86/bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;%PATH%

Remember to move the files out from the external Scripts folder(not the original Scripts folder found in Python27).

---

Originally posted by [RJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/2492/rj/) with karma: 48 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-05-29**:
It does actually say "add C:\Python27\ and C:\Python27\Scripts to your PATH." You can do that in setup.bat, or in windows user/system environment variable settings, or even in registry.

**Comment by [marco.puni](https://answers.ros.org/users/2474/marco.puni/) on 2012-05-30**:
thank you both, I just solved in this way yesterday before reading this, I was coming here now to write the solution =) thank you the same!!!